# Guardar log con un boton php

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Buen día tengo un botón php de esta manera.

```
echo CHtml::button(Yii::t('site', 'Help (F2)'), array('id' => 'run_example'));
```

que llama una función js:

```
<script> $("#run_example").click(function(){ Sideshow.start({ listAll:true });}); </script>
```

Lo que necesito hacer es que cuando un usuario haga clic en el botón se envíe la información de usuario como nombre de usuario, fecha y hora de la acción.

los datos de log son tomados en el archivo LoginForm.php

```
class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe;
    public $language;
    public $loginMobile;
    private $_identity;

    /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     * The rules state that username and password are required,
     * and password needs to be authenticated.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            // username and password are required
            array('username, password, language', 'required'),
            // rememberMe needs to be a boolean
            array('rememberMe, loginMobile', 'boolean'),
            // password needs to be authenticated
            array('password', 'authenticate'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Declares attribute labels.
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'rememberMe'=>Yii::t('site','Remember me next time'),
            'username' => Yii::t('site','Username'),
            'password' => Yii::t('site','Password'),
            'language' => Yii::t('site','Languages'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Authenticates the password.
     * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
     */
    public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
    {
        if(!$this->hasErrors())
        {
            $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
            if(!$this->_identity->authenticate()){
                switch($this->_identity->errorCode){

                        case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID:
                                $this->addError('username',Yii::t('site','Incorrect username'));
                                break;
                        case UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID:
                                $this->addError('password',Yii::t('site','Incorrect password'));
                                break;
                        case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INACTIVE:
                                $this->addError('username',Yii::t('site','Your Accout Not active'));
                                break;
                        case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_LOCKED:
                                $this->addError('username',Yii::t('site','The user is blocked, please wait a few minutes before trying again'));
                                break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in the user using the given username and password in the model.
     * @return boolean whether login is successful
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if($this->_identity===null)
        {
            $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
            $this->_identity->authenticate();
        }
        if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
        {
            $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 3600*24; // 30 days
            //$duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
            Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
            Yii::app()->session['login']=true;
            //Se agrega logica para accesos desde Dispositivos Moviles
            Yii::app()->session['loginMobile']=isset($_POST['LoginForm'])?($_POST['LoginForm']['loginMobile']=='1'?true:false):false;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

No se muy bien como hacerlo tengo entendido que se puede hacer con ajax pero no lo he usado así que no tengo idea de como hacerlo..

Espero me puedan ayudar; muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún framework? ¿Dónde están los datos que dices que quieres mandar: nombre, fecha, etc?

Comment: Si, estoy usando Yii framework. y los datos por ejemplo en una variable de Yii::log. la hora y fecha creo poder extraerla del servidor.

Comment: Pues eso, deberías [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/203860/edit) poniendo al etiqueta de `Yii` y decir también **dónde se encuentran los datos que quieres enviar**. Si es un log, debes decir dónde se encuentra ese log, supongo. Se trata de que des los detalles necesarios para que alguien te pueda ayudar.

Comment: ok la editare muchas gracias...